# Count combinations (not permutations) of column values that may contain NA / missing values

Tags: r

I struggle a bit to count combinations of values found in several columns that may contain missing values (NA).

In columns without NA, I would do the following:

```r
set.seed(42)
foo <- data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:20], 10, replace = T),
                   b = sample(letters[1:20], 10, replace = T),
                   c = sample(letters[1:20], 10, replace = T))

# sorting with base::apply, and converting the result to a data frame
foo_sorted <- as.data.frame(t(apply(foo, 1, sort)))

# I can now pass a counting function such as dplyr::count()
# In this example all rows are unique combinations. 
dplyr::count(foo_sorted, V1, V2, V3)
#>    V1 V2 V3 n
#> 1   a  b  t 1
#> 2   a  c  r 1
#> 3   c  d  o 1
#> 4   d  h  m 1
#> 5   d  k  o 1
#> 6   e  e  q 1
#> 7   e  g  o 1
#> 8   e  n  t 1
#> 9   h  j  r 1
#> 10  i  j  q 1
```

But this fails when NA are in the data frame:

```r
foo2 <- data.frame(a = sample(letters[1:20], 10, replace = T),
                   b = sample(letters[11:31], 10, replace = T),
                   c = sample(letters[21:41], 10, replace = T))

foo2_sorted <- as.data.frame(t(apply(foo2, 1, sort))) 
# results in a nested data frame, on which dplyr::count() won't work as expected. 
dplyr::count(foo2_sorted, V1, V2, V3)
#>   V1 V2      V3 n
#> 1  d  d p, r, y 1
```

I feel this whole apply thing may be an awkward approach, so any idea for a different approach also very welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `na.last = TRUE` to the `apply` call (it's an argument to `sort`):

```r
foo2_sorted <- as.data.frame(t(apply(foo2, 1, sort, na.last = TRUE))) 

foo2_sorted %>% dplyr::count(V1, V2, V3)
  V1   V2   V3 n
1  b    m    x 1
2  c    l <NA> 1
3  d <NA> <NA> 3
4  e    l <NA> 1
5  m    p    u 1
6  p    q <NA> 1
7  p    r    y 1
8  r <NA> <NA> 1
```

Comment: Thanks, Allan. Awesome. I did not think of checking `?sort` oops :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use also use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
foo2 %>%
    pmap_dfr(~ sort(c(...), na.last = TRUE)) %>% 
    dplyr::count(select(., everything()))
    # // or use
    # dplyr::count(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#  a     b     c         n
#  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
#1 b     m     x         1
#2 c     l     <NA>      1
#3 d     <NA>  <NA>      3
#4 e     l     <NA>      1
#5 m     p     u         1
#6 q     p     <NA>      1
#7 r     p     y         1
#8 r     <NA>  <NA>      1
```